# How to check if Discord.py bot is already connected to voice channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

As the title says I have a discord.py bot that joins a voice channel, but I want to add some sort of check so the bot prints out a message along the lines of 'Already connected to voice channel' but I cant figure out how to check if it is connected.

code:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    audio_source = 'song.mp3'
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=str(ctx.author.voice.channel))
    await voice_channel.connect()
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_source))
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-arrange your code like so:

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice_client:
        await ctx.send('Already connected to voice channel')
        return

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'))
```

[`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get) returns `None` if it doesn't find anything. In this case, if `voice_client` is `None`, the bot isn't connected to any channel.

However, if your bot is connected, `voice_client` will be a `discord.VoiceClient` object, and the `if` statement will be executed.