# Get id of voice channel where bot is connected to

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I Want to get the voice channel ID of the voice channel where the bot is connected to. is there any command for it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if Discord.py bot is already connected to voice channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550547/how-to-check-if-discord-py-bot-is-already-connected-to-voice-channel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to access `discord.ext.commands.Bot`'s Voice Clients, which can allow you to see voice activity.

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.command(name="voice")
async def voice(ctx):
    voice_client = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice_client:
        return await ctx.reply("I am not currently connected to a voice channel!")

    voice_channel = voice_client.channel
    voice_channel_id = voice_channel.id
```